# Is it possible to specify WiredTiger compression configuration in Spring Data?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a Java application that connects to MongoDB through Spring Boot. The version of MongoDB that I has is v3.4 and I would like to configure WiredTiger storage engine, especially the compression algorithm, through application properties. I looked at the MongoDB section in this page: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html and there does not seem to be any mention of WiredTiger. Is this kind of configuration currently not supported in Spring Boot?

Comment: Sundar, the choice of a storage engine is made on the Mongo server side. It's not related to the client configuration/support. That said, configure the storage engine options in your MongoDB server and connect as usual to your server.

Comment: mp911de, I see your point. However, in this case, I am trying to configure per-collection compression options that needs to apply to collections that are created while the application is running.

Comment: This wasn't clear from the question. Use the native MongoDB API to specify these options in `CreateCollectionOptions.storageEngineOptions`.

Comment: Thanks, mp911de. This was helpful.